# Set timeout while loading image in Div Background

Tags: javascript, html

I am loading an image as background url for a Div:-

```
<div style="background-image: url('image.jpg'),url('fallback.jpg');"></div>
```

As I understand, fallback image will be shown if there is any error while calling `image.jpg`. :-

1. Will it also handle timeout errors when calling for image.jpg?
2. If yes, what is the timeout duration?
3. How could I control this timeout duration?

**EDIT:** Just understood from comments that above is not fallback, just loading one over another. What I need is to set a timeout and show alternate image after original is not loaded in timeout.

Comment: It's not a fallback-image it's just another background-image on top of the first one https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds

Comment: Oops. I have updated my question.

Comment: Seems hacky. Wouldn't it be easier to optimize the image so that the user can load it faster? Quick tip: reduce color quality until it becomes visible, then increase them to be safe. No visible changes but a lot smaller.

Comment: That's what is already done. We have a server which will decrease image quality and return the image. But I need to handle the cases when server is either down or take too much time to respond.

Basically we definitely need to show an image.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to find out the time taken by an image to be loaded after the set timeout, since it might take a little longer than you think depending on the size of the image. You have to just worry about the order in which you are assigning css properties to your fallback image. Like, setting "no-repeat" for the first one, and the opposite to the second on. Her, you can refer this **https://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/**

Comment: Thanks, so I don't need to load multiple images, just a fallback image when the original one is taking too much time!

Comment: Yeah!. You can do that too.